# Error handling using decorator in python

Tags: python, oop, error-handling

I am using following model:

```
import time

class A:
    def do_action_1(self):
        print("A: action 1")

    def do_action_2(self):
        print("A: action 2")
        raise Exception

class B:
    def __init__(self,A):
        self.a = A
        self.status = None

    def call_action_1(self):
        self.a.do_action_1()

    def call_action_2(self):
        self.a.do_action_2()

a = A()
b = B(a)

while True:
    try:
        print("call action 1")
        b.call_action_1()
        print("call action 2")
        b.call_action_2()
    except Exception as e:
        print ("exception catched")
        while True:
            try:
                b.call_action_2()
                break
            except Exception:
                print ("exception catched")
                print ("waiting 3s ...")
                time.sleep(3)
```

I need somehow modify `b.status`, when `a.do_action_2`, which is called from inside B, raises exception.
`b.call_action_2` is called many times on different places so hard-coding `try except` is not what i want, also is not an elegant. I was trying to use some kind of decorators but i have failed always. Looks i am missing something.

Please let me know i f you have any advice. Also any comments on design are welcome.

Regards

j

Comment: fixed mistake i  comment - b.do_action_2 fixed to b.call_action_2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally done using decorator:

```
import time

global x
x = 0

def errorDecorator(func):#check if it is called by correct class need be done
    def wrapper(self,*args):
        try:
            return func(self,*args)
        except ZeroDivisionError as e:
            print ('error catched and processed ')
            global x
            x = 1 + x
            self.status='updated' + str(x)
            raise e
    return wrapper

class A:
    def do_action_1(self):
        print("A: action 1")

    def do_action_2(self):
        print("A: action 2")
        1/0

class B:
    def __init__(self,A):
        self.a = A
        self.status = None

    def call_action_1(self):
        self.a.do_action_1()

    @errorDecorator
    def call_action_2(self):
        self.a.do_action_2()

a = A()
b = B(a)

while True:
    print (b.status)
    try:
        print("call action 1")
        b.call_action_1()
        print("call action 2")
        b.call_action_2()
    except Exception as e:
        while True:
            try:
                print (b.status)
                b.call_action_2()
                break
            except ZeroDivisionError:
                time.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your problem, but I'll have a stab at it.

The general idea with a decorator is that you want to add behavior to a class you already like, but cannot change directly for some reason.

You basically want to wrap a new class around the original class and give it additional behavior.

When you do that you want to push as much of the new functionality into the new decorator so that you don't have to change code anywhere else.

In your example the biggest thing is that status is part of class B, not class A. You also want to move all the retry logic into class B.

It could look something like this:

```
import time

class A:
    def do_action_1(self):
        print("A: action 1")

    def do_action_2(self):
        print("A: action 2")
        raise Exception

class B:
    def __init__(self,A):
        self.a = A
        self.status = 'None'

    def call_action_1(self):
        self.a.do_action_1()

    def call_action_2(self):
        while self.status != 'Success':
            try:
                self.a.do_action_2()
                self.status = 'Success'
            except Exception as e:
                self.status = 'Failure'
                print("exception caught inside decorator B")
                print("> waiting 3s ...")
                time.sleep(3)
            ## some sort of safety maximum attempt should be implemented so you don't get into an infinite loop here. 

a = A()
b = B(a)

while True:
    try:
        print("call action 1")
        b.call_action_1()
        print("call action 2")
        b.call_action_2()
    except Exception as e:
        print("exception in main")
```

To be safe, you should implement some sort of maximum number of attempts for class B so that it stops trying after X attempts at do_action_2().

Comment: well, your code contains the same error as the OP code, which should grant you a straight -1.  There is no "A" instance associated to "B" objects, still, they try to call A.do_action methods as if "self.a" inside a B object was an instance.

Comment: I'm not following. I'm not seeing where there is a call to A.do_action inside class B? The code runs as expected for me.

Comment: just remove the ctach all `Except` clause and try to run that.